# How can I display all books with price less than 70.00. from reading the file?

Tags: c

```
struct book{
    int code;
    char title[20];
    char author[20];
    char publisher[20];
    char year[4];
    double price;
};

struct book book1, mybook[100];

FILE *tf, *bf;

int main(){
    int i;

    tf = fopen("mybook.txt","r");
    bf = fopen("myEbooks","wb");

    for(i=1; i<100; i++){
        fscanf(tf,"%i\n", &book1.code);
        fscanf(tf,"%[^\n]\n", book1.title);
        fscanf(tf,"%[^\n]\n", book1.author);
        fscanf(tf,"%[^\n]\n", book1.publisher);
        fscanf(tf,"%[^\n]\n", &book1.year);
        fscanf(tf,"%lf\n", &book1.price);

        fwrite(&book1, sizeof(struct book),1, bf);

    }
    printf("\nBinary Stock file successfully generated!!\n");

    fclose(tf);
    fclose(bf);

    return 0;
}
```

Code above for generating binary file from reading .txt file.  The code below is for reading the binary file.

```
struct book{
    int code;
    char title[20];
    char author[20];
    char publisher[20];
    char year[4];
    double price;
};

int main(){
    int data;
    int record;
    double price;
    struct book book1;

    FILE * bf;

    bf = fopen("myEbooks", "rb");

    fseek(bf,1,SEEK_END);
    record = (ftell(bf)/sizeof(struct book));
    rewind(bf);

    printf("Title\t\t  Code\t\tAuthor\t\tPublisher\t Year\tPrice\n");

    for(data=0;data<100;data++){
        fread(&book1, sizeof(struct book), 1, bf);

        printf("%s\t\t  %i\t      %s\t       %s\t     %s\t %0.2lf\n", book1.title, book1.code, book1.author, book1.publisher, book1.year, book1.price);
    }

    fclose(bf);
    return 0;
}
```

- How do I insert a condition?
- Where do I need to insert the condition statement?
- How can I display only the books with price less than 70.00. from reading the file?

Comment: Consider posting a part of `myEbooks` file alongside with your question, so that people can test your code!

Comment: It would be better if you can add the data in mybook.txt , so that we can reproduce the code, and do the specific changes you want. It plays an  important role in giving you a presise and correct answer.

Comment: It would be better if the structure definition was in a header file that is included by the two programs.  That way you can be sure that both programs agree on the structure, and it is crucial that they do agree.  I don't see a difference, but in the long run, it would be silly to risk a discrepancy.  You don't check any of the I/O operations.  In particular, you don't check that the read operations are successful.

Comment: `char year[4];` --> `char year[4+1];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the number of records are less than `100`, you need to change your first snippet code for the last `fscanf` as follows to only read as many times as there are records in `mybook.txt`.

```
if(fscanf(tf,"%lf\n", &book1.price) != EOF)
    fwrite(&book1, sizeof(struct book),1, bf);
else
    break;
```

Also, for the second snippet code, you need to change `100` to `record` and have a condition like `book1.price < 70` to only print out books with price less than `70`.

```
for(data = 0; data < record; data++)
{
    fread(&book1, sizeof(struct book), 1, bf);
    if(book1.price < 70)
        printf("%s\t\t  %i\t      %s\t       %s\t     %s\t %0.2lf\n",
                book1.title, book1.code, book1.author, book1.publisher,
                book1.year, book1.price);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you want to display the books with price less than 70 on the screen.

Also, you are reading 100 structures. This is OK, if you write exactly 100 structures. If you have less than 100, then it will not be printed properly. You can change that by checking the return value of `fread`. If it is 1, then one structure has been successfully read.

In the second file,

```
while(fread(&book1, sizeof(struct book), 1, bf) == 1) 
{
    if (book1.price <= 70)
    {
       printf("%s\t\t  %i\t      %s\t       %s\t     %s\t %0.2lf\n", book1.title, book1.code, book1.author, book1.publisher, book1.year, book1.price);
   }
}
```